# Unable to use data pump utility in Oracle to import data to another server

Tags: linux, database, oracle, database-backups, datapump

I am using this command:

```
impdp atif/atif@192.168.67.68:1521/serv1 DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=mltpltblbkp.dmp LOGFILE=mltpltblbkp.log
```

to import data from one server to another.

this is my data_pump_dir path:/u01/app/oracle/admin/serv1/dpdump/

I have granted these privileges to the user

```
grant datapump_exp_full_database to atif;
grant datapump_imp_full_database to atif;
grant read, write on directory data_pump_dir to system;
```

When I run the command, I get the following errors:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file `"/u01/app/oracle/admin/serv1/dpdump/mltpltblbkp.dmp" for read`
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
```

can someone help here?

Comment: You can't impdp from a @ remote location like that. Move the file over to the local server using OS utilities (sftp, scp, etc..) and import it there.

Comment: /u01/app/oracle/admin/serv1/dpdump/mltpltblbkp.dmp has to exist on your database server and be readable by the user that runs the database (usually oracle). If your file is on a remote server and you don't want to copy it to the db server you could use NFS to make it appear to be local.